# "this way" or "that way"

Tags: phrase-meaning, difference, phrase-usage

Is "this way" used correctly in the following? Or should "That way" be used instead? What's the difference?

> If you don't know how to ask John for help, just buy him a beer. **This way**, he'll help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`This` & `that` are similar in function, but they introduce a difference wherein `this` is associated with *proximity* (being closer), and `that` is associated with *remoteness* (being more distant). This distinction applies to spatial, time-related, and conceptual aspects.

I believe in your sample sentence it is used as a [`determiner`](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/that#collins-section).

---

Since you haven't bought John a beer yet, moreover, we don't know whether you will actually do so or not, the discussed occurrence is a *remote possibility* (both time-wise, in the future, and both spatially, as you will be somewhere else when/if that happens).

That's why the correct determiner for your example scenario is the one associated with remoteness: `that`.

> If you don't know how to ask John for help, just buy him a beer. That way, he'll help you.

Comment: Can "As a result" be used instead of "That way" there?

Comment: @Apollyon I'd say no, for two reasons: 1.) "As a result" I feel, implies a sort of _guarantee_. Like, _I know_ that John will behave that way for sure. But the truth is that noone can guarantee that, John will decide himself. 2.) The context of the sentence is a joke, a banter. The expression "as a result" does not fit well into a joke. It's so much not funny, that it would kill any joke. This expression is rather used in dry, technical contexts.